# ggplot2 use NA values in Barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, read.csv

I'm starting with Rstudio and ShinyApp and i have some problems, this because i made a this code and at first it work very easy but when i tried to deploy my app, my barplot show me NA values, i have some ideas why but as i said before, im very new in this an i wonder if you can help me please.
Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')

santander<-read.csv("./Data/Panel modelo liderazgo-Base carga oficial.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",encoding =  "UTF-8",stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings=c("","NA"))

cuestionario<-read.csv("./Data/Panel modelo liderazgo-Base cuestionarios respondidos-30052017.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",encoding =  "UTF-8",na.strings = c("","NA"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


shinyServer(function(input,output){

      #Filter for person that i will show his stats


  bar<-reactive({ data.frame(filter(santander,NOMBRE==input$Nombre))})


  herramienta <-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$Nombre_apfut,bar()$Nombre_Hacercosassuc,bar()$Nombre_CrearCult,bar()$Nombre_vocserv)))})
  prompers <-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$Prom_tot_apfut,bar()$Prom_tot_Hacercosassuc,bar()$Prom_tot_CrearCult,bar()$Prom_tot_vocserv)))})
  eva_persona<-reactive({do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, herr=herramienta(), perso=prompers()))})

  df.m <- reactive({melt(eva_persona(), id.var=c("herr"))})

  #Ranking person

  promtotal<-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$Prom_tot)))})
  ranking<-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$RANKING)))})
  tabla1<-reactive({do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, "Nota Global"=promtotal(), Ranking=ranking()))})

  #information about person (Nombre=Name)

  resp<-reactive({data.frame(filter(cuestionario,cuestionario$NOMBRE==input$Nombre))})


  #Information chart "apoyando el futuro"

  encabezado<-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$Nombre_Prom_asc_apfut,bar()$Nombre_Prom_eng_apfut,bar()$Nombre_Prom_gptw_apfut)))})

  nota1<-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$Prom_asc_apfut,bar()$Prom_eng_apfut,bar()$Prom_gptw_apfut)))})
  apo_fut<-reactive({do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, encabezado=encabezado(), nota1=nota1()))})

  grafo <- reactive({melt(apo_fut(), id.var=c("encabezado"))})



  #Information chart "hacer que las cosas sucedan"

  nota2<-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$Prom_asc_Hacercosassuc,bar()$Prom_eng_Hacercosassuc,bar()$Prom_gptw_CrearCult)))})
  cosas<-reactive({do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, encabezado=encabezado(), nota2=nota2()))})

  grafo2 <- reactive({melt(cosas(), id.var=c("encabezado"))})



  #Information chart "Crear Cultura"

  nota3<-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$Prom_asc_CrearCult,bar()$Prom_eng_CrearCult,bar()$Prom_gptw_Hacercosassuc)))})
  crear<-reactive({do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, encabezado=encabezado(), nota3=nota3()))})

  grafo3 <- reactive({melt(cosas(), id.var=c("encabezado"))})

  #Information chart "Vocacion de servicio"

  nota4<-reactive({as.list(unique(c(bar()$Prom_asc_vocserv,bar()$Prom_eng_vocserv,bar()$Prom_gptw_vocserv)))})
  voca<-reactive({do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, encabezado=encabezado(), nota4=nota4()))})

  grafo4 <- reactive({melt(voca(), id.var=c("encabezado"))})

  #  Chart "dimension modelo"

  c4=c("Apoyando futuro","Hacer que las cosas sucedan","Crear Cultura","Vocacion de servicio")

  p<-reactive({ggplot(df.m(),aes(x="Dimensiones del Modelo",y="",title = "Evaluacion dimensiones")) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = herr, y = value, fill = c4), 
               stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +

      geom_text(aes(y=value, x=herr,label=value), vjust=1.6, hjust = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width=0.9), 
                color="black", size=3.5)+

      scale_fill_manual("\n", values = c("Apoyando futuro"="chartreuse3","Hacer que las cosas sucedan"="mediumorchid3","Crear Cultura"="deepskyblue2","Vocacion de servicio"="gold"), 
                        labels = c(" Persona", " Banco Santander")) +

      labs(x="Dimensiones del Modelo",y="",title = "Evaluacion dimensiones") +

      theme_minimal()+ theme(legend.position="none")+  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"), 
                                                             axis.text = element_text(size=10),
                                                             strip.text.y = element_text(size=12))
  })

  #Chart "apoyando el futuro"  

  c1=c("Ascendente","Engagement","Great Place to Work")

  a<-reactive({ggplot(grafo(),aes(x="",y="",title = "Apoyando el Futuro")) +

      geom_bar(aes(x = encabezado, y = value, fill = c1), stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +

      geom_text(aes(y=value, x=encabezado,label=value), vjust=1.6, hjust = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width=0.9), 
                color="black", size=3.5)+

      scale_fill_manual( values = c("Ascendente"="chartreuse4","Engagement"="chartreuse3","Great Place to Work"="chartreuse2") ) +

      labs(x="",y="",title = ("Apoyando el Futuro")) +

      theme_minimal()+ theme(legend.position="none")+  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"), 
                                                               axis.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
                                                               strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))
  })

  #Chart "hacer que las cosas sucedan"  

  c2=c("Ascendente","Engagement","Great Place to Work")

  b<-reactive({ggplot(grafo2(),aes(x="",y="",title = "Hacer que las cosas Sucedan")) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = encabezado, y = value, fill = c2), 
               stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +

      geom_text(aes(y=value, x=encabezado,label=value), vjust=1.6, hjust = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width=0.9), 
                color="black", size=3.5)+

      scale_fill_manual("/n", values = c("Ascendente"="mediumorchid4","Engagement"="mediumorchid3","Great Place to Work"="mediumorchid1"), 
                        labels = c("Persona")) +

      labs(x="",y="",title = ("Hacer que las cosas Sucedan")) +

      theme_minimal()+ theme(legend.position="none")+  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"), 
                                                               axis.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
                                                               strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))
  })

  #Chart "crear cultura"

  c5=c("Ascendente","Engagement","Great Place to Work")

  d<-reactive({ggplot(grafo3(),aes(x="",y="",title = "Crear Cultura")) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = encabezado, y = value, fill = c5), 
               stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +

      geom_text(aes(y=value, x=encabezado,label=value), vjust=1.6, hjust = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width=0.9), 
                color="black", size=3.5)+

      scale_fill_manual("/n", values = c("Ascendente"="deepskyblue4","Engagement"="deepskyblue3","Great Place to Work"="deepskyblue"), 
                        labels = c("Persona")) +

      labs(x="",y="",title = ("Crear Cultura")) +

      theme_minimal()+ theme(legend.position="none")+  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"), 
                                                               axis.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
                                                               strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))
  })

  #Chart "vocacion de servicio"

  c3=c("Ascendente","Engagement","Great Place to Work")


  v<-reactive({ggplot(grafo4(),aes(x="",y="",title = "Vocación de Servicio")) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = encabezado, y = value, fill = c3), 
               stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +

      geom_text(aes(y=value, x=encabezado,label=value), vjust=1.6, hjust = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width=0.9), 
                color="black", size=3.5)+

      scale_fill_manual("/n", values = c("Ascendente"="gold4","Engagement"="gold3","Great Place to Work"="gold1"), 
                        labels = c(" Persona", "")) +

      labs(x="",y="",title = ("Vocación de Servicio")) +

      theme_minimal()+ theme(legend.position="none")+  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"), 
                                                               axis.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
                                                               strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))
  })






  #OUTPUTS UI  

  output$seg6<-renderUI({

     selectInput("division","Elija División",c("Todos",santander$Division_UR))


  })



  output$seg2<-renderUI({  

    selectInput("piramide","Seleccione Jefatura",c("Todos",santander$Piramide[santander$Division_UR==input$division]),selected=NULL
                ,multiple=FALSE)

  })

  output$seg3<-renderUI({  

    selectInput("area","Seleccione Área:",c("Todos",santander$area_UR[santander$Piramide==input$piramide & 
                                                                santander$Division_UR==input$division]),selected=NULL
                ,multiple=FALSE)

  })


  output$seg4<-renderUI({  

    selectInput("gerencia","Seleccione Gerencia:",c("Todos",santander$Gerencia_UR[santander$Piramide==input$piramide & 
                                                                            santander$Division_UR==input$division & 
                                                                            santander$area_UR==input$area]),selected=NULL
                ,multiple=FALSE)

  })


  output$seg5<-renderUI({  




    selectInput("Nombre","Seleccione Líder:",c(santander$NOMBRE[santander$Piramide==input$piramide & 
                                                                  santander$Division_UR==input$division & 
                                                                  santander$area_UR==input$area & 
                                                                  santander$Gerencia_UR==input$gerencia]),selected=NULL
                ,multiple=FALSE)

  })


  output$graf1<-renderPlot({  
    p()
  })

  output$tabla1<-renderTable({
    tabla1()
  })

  output$tabla2<-renderTable({
    resp()
  },aoColumnDefs = list(list(sWidth=c("Nombre"), aTargets=list(0))))

  output$graf2<-renderPlot({  
    a()
  })

  output$graf3<-renderPlot({  
    b()
  })

  output$graf4<-renderPlot({  
    d()
  })
  output$graf5<-renderPlot({  
    v()
  })

}
)
```

And ui.R is:

```
santander<-read.csv("./Data/Panel modelo liderazgo-Base carga oficial.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",encoding ="LATIN1",na.strings = c("","NA"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

cuestionario<-read.csv("./Data/Panel modelo liderazgo-Base cuestionarios respondidos-30052017.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",encoding =  "LATIN1",na.strings = c("","NA"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


shinyUI(
  fluidPage(


  br(),

  fixedRow( 
    column(6,div(img(src="SantanderRed.png", height=60,width=260))),
    column(3, offset=3,div(img(src="8534538-0-img-logo-responsive.png",height=60,width=240 )),alrig="left")

  ) ,

  br(),
  br(),

  fluidRow( 

    column(12,titlePanel(title=strong("Ficha de resultados por Líder")))),

  br(),

  sidebarPanel( fluidRow(

    column(6,uiOutput("seg6"), 

           uiOutput("seg2"),

           uiOutput("seg3"),

           uiOutput("seg4")),


    column(6,uiOutput("seg5"))),width=170),


  titlePanel(strong("Nota Global Líder")),
  br(),



  fluidRow(  column(6, tableOutput("tabla1"))),
  br(),
  fluidRow    (  column(6,tableOutput("tabla2")) ),




  br(),

  titlePanel(strong("Evaluación Dimensiones del Modelo")),

  plotOutput("graf1"),




  br(),
  titlePanel(strong(h2("Evaluación por Instrumento"))),
  br(),
  fluidRow( column(3,plotOutput("graf2")),

            column(3,plotOutput("graf3")),

            column(3,plotOutput("graf4")),

            column(3,plotOutput("graf5"))

  )


)



)
```

Talking about the data, i can't publish this one, but if this one is filtered and then we create "bar", "bar" looks like this:

```
bar2<-data.frame(UR =c("3808"),
           NOMBRE  =c("LORENA PAZ FUENTES GONZALEZ"),
           Piramide =c("JEFATURAS"),
           Division_UR =c("DIVISION BANCA COMERCIAL"),
           Gerencia_UR =c("RED BANCO"),
           area_UR =c("TERRITORIAL OCTAVA"),
           Prom_tot =c("1,6"),
           RANKING =c("1"),
           Nombre_apfut =c("Apoyando futuro"),
           Prom_tot_apfut =c("1,5"),
           Prom_banco_apfut =c("-0,014"),
           Nombre_Hacercosassuc =c("Hacer que las cosas sucedan"),
           Prom_tot_Hacercosassuc =c("1,6"),
           Prom_banco_Hacercosassuc =c("-0,0133"),
           Nombre_CrearCult =c("Crear Cultura"),
           Prom_tot_CrearCult =c("1,5"),
           Prom_banco_CrearCult =c("-0,0108"),
           Nombre_vocserv =c("Vocacion de servicio"),
           Prom_tot_vocserv =c("1,7"),
           Prom_banco_vocserv =c("-0,0055"),
           Nombre_Prom_asc_apfut =c("Ascendente"),
           Prom_asc_apfut =c("1,9"),
           Nombre_Prom_eng_apfut =c("Engagement"),
           Prom_eng_apfut =c("1"),
           Nombre_Prom_gptw_apfut =c("Great Place to Work"),
           Prom_gptw_apfut =c(""),
           Nombre_Prom_asc_Hacercosassuc =c("Ascendente"),
           Prom_asc_Hacercosassuc =c("2,1"),
           Nombre_Prom_eng_Hacercosassuc =c("Engagement"),
           Prom_eng_Hacercosassuc =c("1,1"),
           Nombre_Prom_gptw_Hacercosassuc =c("Great Place to Work"),
           Prom_gptw_Hacercosassuc =c(""),
           Nombre_Prom_asc_CrearCult =c("Ascendente"),
           Prom_asc_CrearCult =c("1,8"),
           Nombre_Prom_eng_CrearCult =c("Engagement"),
           Prom_eng_CrearCult =c("1,1"),
           Nombre_Prom_gptw_CrearCult =c("Great Place to Work"),
           Prom_gptw_CrearCult =c(""),
           Nombre_Prom_asc_vocserv =c("Ascendente"),
           Prom_asc_vocserv =c("2"),
           Nombre_Prom_eng_vocserv =c("Engagement"),
           Prom_eng_vocserv =c("1,3"),
           Nombre_Prom_gptw_vocserv =c("Great Place to work"),
           Prom_gptw_vocserv =c("")
           )
```

I know that maybe is very confussed and weird but actually works, i just need that my barplot don't take that NA values.
[My ggplot with NA Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKrKZ.png)

Comment: Please provide data and, if possible, rewrite comments inside the code in English, so it would be easier to replicate

Comment: Sorry but i can't plublish the data, i working with private data so i can't, but i will change the comments! you are right! sorry

Comment: Then please simulate data so the structure of dataframe will be the same as in the original dataset. Otherwise it is difficult to understand what to feed Shiny :)